# Taylor Polynomials, finding the upper error bound

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find the second order Taylor polynomial $T_2(x)$ for $f(x)=x^3ln(x)$ about $a=1$. I got $x - 1 + 2.5(x - 1)^2$, which is correct.

I was then asked to use Taylor's theorem to give the error term, $E_2(x) = f(x) - T_2(x)$ as a function of $x$ and some $z$ between $1$ and $x$. I got $\dfrac{1}{6}(6\ln z+11)(x-1)^3$, which is correct.

I was then asked the following:

> Use the fact that $1<z<x$ and the fact that $0 < \ln(z)<1$ for all $1<z<2$ to find an upper bound on $E_2(x)$ when $1<x<2$.

I appreciate any help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given $E_2(x)$ and that $\ln{z}<1 $ you have that 
$$
\frac{(6\ln{z}+11)(x-1)^3}{6} < \frac{(6+11)(x-1)^3}{6} = \frac{17(x-1)^3}{6}
$$